# Why can't I delete answers at 20k rep?

Tags: discussion, privileges, vote-to-delete

[image]

I have 20k reputation on Puzzling. This answer does not meet the standards of our site, and I wanted to vote to delete. Why can't I?

Comment: I think it needs negative reputaion score (maybe -3 or so) *or* to be two days old.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot find the exact requirements but I am pretty certain you cannot immediately vote to delete answers. Unless they are very poor, at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It needs a score of -1 or lower](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) to be able to be deleted by people with trusted user privileges.

Vote it down first, comment so the OP knows what to improve (if possible), flag it as VLQ or NAA, and then you can cast your delete vote.